# How can I store predefined values sorted according to date in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, object, quicksort

I want to store predefined(hardcoded) values in person object and display it on the screen with date sorted.How can I achieve that?

### Here are the problem and my code.

A society keeps a list of members and uses a program to store the list.For each member, the following information is recorded

membership number
surname
the first name
the date that the person joined the society
whether or not they are still a member
The program is required to offer three options
1) Enter the details of the member(either current or past member).Members may be entered in any order.You can assume the membership number is available from some existing list so just needs to be entered into the program along with other data.

2) Prompt for the current date and produce as output a list of people who have been a member for at least 10years(and still a member currently)The list should be in order of date joined and split up according to how long they have been a member(50+years,40+years etc)If there is more than one person who joined on the same day, they should be given in alphabetical order of surname and if they have same surname, first name.The list should produce by sorting the set of members into the order required.

3)Prompt for membership number and mark the person's membership as not current.

Output should look something like this

```
Long-standing members at 20/02/2012

50+years
mem no date joined name
432 21/07/1963 Xerxes Smith
3103 20/02/1968 Aloysius Baker

40+years
mem no. date joined name
4934 21/02/1968 Hermione Turner
0123 08/06/1975 Bartholomew Wright
1498 08/06/1975 Ermintrude Wright

30+year
```

—————————————————————————————————

Comment: Store your date in a format understandable by a computer.  Convert it to a string when displaying it.  You should be sorting an int or some sort of structure or class with comparison methods.

Comment: or alternately/and, use `qsort` or `std::qsort`.  All you need to do at that point is write a function that can compare two dates as you've stored them.

Comment: @zzxyz it is `C++`, not `C`. `std::sort` is preferred

Comment: @Fureeish  cant sort using std::sort .I have to implement my own sort method.I have done that but cant sort the existing list hardcoded in my code.Its in existpersons() function

Comment: @zzxyz I cant use qsort or std sort.I have to implement my own function for sorting.Please tell me how to sort the existing list in my codementioned  in existpersons() function

Comment: @AdarshPatel - Ok, the first thing you still want to do is write a function that takes two of your dates (however you choose to store them), and tells the calling function which is bigger.  Now your sorting function can treat them like anything else.

Comment: @Fureeish - Roger that.  Thanks.

Comment: Adding to @zzxyz's comment - that preferably would be `bool operator <`

Comment: @Fureeish I tried doing that but the dates dont get sorted yearwise.

Comment: @zzxyz I tried doing that but its getting difficult for me.Can you help me on that?

Comment: @AdarshPatel it means you implemented it incorrectly. It makes sorting exactly as you describe. If the sorting did not work, it means that you either made a mistake in sorting algorithm, or in the `operator <` implementation

Answer (score 0):

I'm only giving you bubble sort.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class person
{
public:
  person(string doj)
  {
    memset(&m_doj, 0, sizeof(tm));
    std::istringstream ssDate(doj);
    ssDate >> get_time(&m_doj, "%d/%m/%Y");
  }
  tm m_doj;
  bool operator> (person &person2)
  {
    return mktime(&m_doj) > mktime(&person2.m_doj);
  }
  void output()
  {
    cout << put_time(&m_doj, "%d/%m/%Y") << "\n";
  }
};

void swap(person *xp, person *yp)
{
  person temp = *xp;
  *xp = *yp;
  *yp = temp;
}

void bubbleSort(person arr[], int n)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)

    // Last i elements are already in place   
    for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
        swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
}

void main()
{
  person people[5] = { person("22/02/2012"), person("21/03/2012"), person("21/02/2018"), person("21/02/1969"), person("20/02/2012") };
  bubbleSort(people, 5);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    people[i].output();
  }
}
```